# HTML, CSS, Media Query (desktop flow scrolling even when unnecessary)

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries

This is a ["newbie" project](https://jvolfe-formpractice.netlify.app/) that i'm studying with, and im trying to work mobile first so i go to desktop flow

When i try to implement the media query for desktop flow, elements don't fit the screen (screen is scrolling even if the elements could fit)??

I tried to change the height of ".container" using percentage but it didn't work as well. The screen is always scrolling while desktop flow, i want that elements fit the entire screen (no scroll page)..

`

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="cont1">
        <header>
          <h1>Learn to code by watching others</h1>
        </header>
        <p>
          See how experienced developers solve problems in real-time. Watching
          scripted tutorials is great, but understanding how developers think is
          invaluable.
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class=" cont2">
        <p class="container-blue-p">
          <strong>Try it free 7 days</strong> then $20/mo. thereafter
        </p>
        <form action="#" id="form" class="form">
          <div class="form-control">
            <input
              type="text"
              name="firstname"
              id="firstname"
              placeholder="First Name"
            />
            <i class="fas fa-exclamation-circle"></i>
            <i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>
            <small>Error Message</small>
          </div>
          [...]
  </div>
  </body>
```

```
@media(min-width:1200px) {
    body {
        background-image: url(images/bg-intro-desktop.png);
    }

    .container {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-areas: "container1 container2";
        grid-template-columns: 50% 50%;
        max-width: 1200px;
    }

    .cont1 {
        display: flex;
        align-items: flex-start;
        justify-content: center;
        grid-area: container1;
    }

    .cont1 header {
        max-width: 50%;
    }

    header h1 {
        text-align: start;
    }

    .cont1 p {
        max-width: 90%;
        text-align: start;
    }

    .cont2 {
        margin-top: 0;
        grid-area: container2;
    }

    .cont1,
    .cont2 {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: center;

    }

    .container-blue-p {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        height: 3em;
    }
}
```

`